# how to build a Poll / Survey type app in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to understand how to create a poll/survey app in rails.

Right now I have the following model:

```
Poll (id, question:string, answer_1:string, answer_2:string, answer_3:string, answer_4:string, answer_5:string)
```

How do I track PollVote per user? Also, how would I then build the form where it shows a poll, with the question and answer(s). And then queries across the PollVote model to see if the user has made any votes?

Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I'd model it something like the following for the most flexibility:

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :responses, :through => :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :poll
  has_many :answers
  has_many :responses, :through => :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :responses
end

class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :answer
end
```

Then you could do things like:

```
Response.count(:conditions => "question_id = #{@question.id} AND answer_id = #{@answer.id}")
```

**Edit**:

Stretching the limits of my expertise, but here's some more code that should get you started with the rest. Not syntax-checked or tested in any way whatsoever. Meant for inspiration more than anything else.

```
class PollsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def show
    @poll = Poll.find(params[:id], :includes => { :questions => { :answers => :responses } } )
    @responses = {}
    @poll.responses.each do |r|
      @responses[r.answer.question.id] = r if r.user == current_user
    end
  end
  ...
end


# in app/views/poll/show.html.haml

%ul
  - @poll.questions.each do |question|
    %li
      %p= question.text
      = form_for (@responses[question.id] || Response.new) do |f|
        - question.answers.each do |ans|
          = f.radio_button :answer, ans.id
          = f.label( ('answer_' << ans.id).to_sym, ans.text )
```

Keep in mind the is probably the easiest but least efficient way to do this. You'll want to move a lot of this processing to the database if you're dealing with a large number of responses.

Also, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196560/ruby-on-rails-specifying-uniqueness-in-db-across-multiple-columns) for dealing with response uniqueness. My code is designed to keep users to one vote per question, but it doesn't actually validate that.

Comment: Thanks Luke but how do I show the form, the view where it shows the question, the answers, and for the user if they voted on a particular answer. That should be shown. They should also be able to change their vote, with only one vote per question. ideas?

Comment: @AnApprentice I added some code to illustrate one way that could be done. See what you think.

Comment: google for "rails counter_cache" ... this will be helpful with fast queries for the number of questions per poll, answers per question, responses per answer, etc