# Best approach for creating a polling app in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My models:

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title
  validates_presence_of :description

  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :responses, through: :questions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, reject_if: lambda { |a| a[:title].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :poll

  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :responses, through: :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, reject_if: lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :responses
end

class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :answer
end
```

When you go to `/polls/.:id` it shows the poll with its corresponding questions and each question with its corresponding answers.

I've been playing around with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479130/how-to-build-a-poll-survey-type-app-in-rails/6479540#6479540) but I don't know what to do from there. I want whomever I send a poll link (/polls/.:id) to to be able to answer that poll. The method described in the answer linked before creates a form for each question.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? (Controllers? Views?) Could you post a link to the rest of your code so we can see where you're at? I'm not sure how to help since your question is a bit vague. Thanks.

Comment: I'm mainly stuck on the view layer of things... how do I get radios/checkboxes to appear on the poll details page? And how do I send that data?

Answer (score 1):

I'd check out the documentation on rails views here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html

There is tons of documentation on how to access and transport data with various form elements.

Comment: Where, exactly? I didn't find something that lead me somewhere.